# Is it possible to replace to uppercase in Visual Studio?

Tags: regex, visual-studio, replace, uppercase

Is it possible to replace *to* upper case in Visual Studio using "Find and Replace" dialog and RegEx (?) à la: `. => Upper(.)`?

Say I have:

```
m_<b>a</b>blabla
```

I want:

```
_<b>A</b>blabla
```

Comment: How many occurrences of the expression are there?  If the number is not huge, then I would probably create an ad-hoc temporary macro to do this.

Comment: @RickL: If you create a macro, the number of expressions should it matter?! I just wonder if possible with Find/Replace.

Comment: Kind of yes, because I would create a macro which would find the next string and uppercase it appropriately.  So you would need to run the macro multiple times to replace all the expressions.  I guess if it's a lot, then it's easy to edit the macro and put a for.. loop in.  I'll answer below how to solve this using temporary macros.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can solve this by using Visual Studio temporary macros.  This is a very powerful, flexible feature which I use all the time for performing repetitive code manipulations.

I'm assuming you're using the C# default key bindings here.

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to bring up the find in files dialogue.
2. Click use "Regular expressions"
3. Set "Find what:" to "`<m_:Ll`"  - words that begin with m, underscore, then a lower case letter;
4. Click "Find all" to search for all occurrences;
5. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to start recording temporary macro;
6. Press <kbd>F8</kbd> to find next occurrence of search expression;
7. Press right cursor, right cursor, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + right cursor (to skip "m_" and then select  the lower case letter);
8. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to uppercase the lower case letter;
9. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to stop recording temporary macro;
10. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to replay temporary macro, which will jump to next expression and uppercase the first letter after the "m_".  You need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> as many times as there are expressions.

Comment: Worth noting macros have been removed from VS2012 ... no can do any more :( Used to use these all the time.

Comment: I used Notepad++ for this since it's not in VS2012: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039226/regex-to-change-to-sentence-case

Comment: [Adding macro support for VS2012/2013/2015](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13353364/1548895)

Comment: Would it be possible to use a macro to "replace all" 26 times (one for each letter)? Then you'd only have to run the macro 26 times, or maybe only once if you can do it in a single macro.

Comment: There are no alternatives for macros at the moment, the [Text Macros for Visual Studio 2012-2017 extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8e2103b6-87cf-4fef-9410-a580c434b602) only support text actions, so nothing about *find next occurence*, but it does uppercase for example.

Comment: For Visual Studio 2019: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=XavierPoinas.TextMacrosforVisualStudio201220132015

Answer (score 10):

If you use Visual Studio Code (instead of Visual Studio) you can use the modifiers: \u\U\l\L

- Sample text: `m_<b>a</b>blabla`
- Find: `m_<b>(.*)</b>`
- Replace: `m_<b>\U$1</b>`
- Sample text after replace: `m_<b>A</b>blabla`

Note: This is only possible in Visual Studio Code 1.29 and later (released August 2020). See https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_49#_case-changing-in-regex-replace

Answer (score 9):

No, Visual Studio does not support that. For a reference of the regular expressions capabilities in VS check:

[Regular Expressions (Visual Studio)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)

---

(Original answer, given due to misinterpreting the original question)

Assuming Visual Studio C# Default key bindings.

There are different ways you can achieve this.

If it's a (variable, method, property, etc) you can use the Rename refactoring to change all instances. This refactoring is invoked by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> key while on the instance you want to rename.

If you perform the change on the definition itself you can also use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to invoke the active refactorings popup and then do the rename all instances.

If it's a string literal you can use the shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> (lowercase) and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> (uppercase) to rapidly switch the case of the selection. This is valid for all text shown in the editor, but most useful for string literals.

Comment: @serhio, I'm afraid Visual Studio only allows you to create tagged expression that you can then reference (/1, /2, etc), but does not support to change those values on the fly.

Comment: FWIW: [VSCode can](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_47#_editor). Copy to it, do your magic and then copy back.

Comment: @LosManos This is pure gold! Whoever approved this change request needs to be given the Turing Award IMO! There's only one thing missing from the feature: the ability to use it in the match string as well! Do you know whether there are any plans to implement this?