# Replace instruction in Visual Studio 2010 with regular expressions

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

was wondering if anyone could help me find the regular expression for this problem. I'd like to replace the following using Visual Studio 2010's built in Find/Replace function:

```
_batch.AddInstruction(InstructionType.Update, "LEG_RES_ID", "N")
```

with

```
_batch.AddInstruction(InstructionType.Update, BpcFields.LegResId, "N")
```

The "LEG_RES_ID" is a placeholder, multiple different strings can occur here. For any string in that position, the equivalent member of BpcFields will be a Pascal-case version of the same string, without the underscores, as in the example above.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think it is possible.

Comment: That `"` after `LegResId` is a typo, right?

Comment: You provide no information about what varies with LEG_RES_ID that makes it impossible to do a normal straight search-and-replace.

Comment: It is possible to search with regexes in visual studio. What are the variables? Why can't you just do:

Find: `_batch.AddInstruction(InstructionType.Update, "LEG_RES_ID", "N")`


Replace with: `_batch.AddInstruction(InstructionType.Update, BpcFields.LegResId", "N")`

Comment: Sorry guys, the "LEG_RES_ID" part is the variable which changes every line. The replacement should be the same word but in pascal case notation.

Comment: @Gabber, I believe because the OP is stating it can be implemented on multiple lines in some cases.

Comment: @Aetherix, please edit the question with your clarification. Thanks!

Comment: Done, hope this helps. If anything is not clear just let me know which part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743836/is-it-possible-to-replace-to-uppercase-in-visual-studio) answer and try to use macros. It seems that it is not possible to changhe the case of text only with regexp unless you have another editor (for example EditPad pro according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159343/convert-a-char-to-upper-case-using-regular-expressions-editpad-pro)).

Another workaround would be to create a program that performs the task you need on text files and use it on your source.