# How to use Regex to 'uppercase and replace' in Visual Studio Code's snippets?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I want to create a snippet on Visual Studio Code 1.33.1 that create a C++ class using the file's name.
First, I want to set up the "include guard", the point is to use the file's name, replace every '.' by a '_' and set it all to uppercase (norm):
`#ifndef FILE_CLASS_HPP //filename: File.class.hpp`

The [VSC documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_transform-examples) provides some variable for the file's name, and some Regex to change to all uppercase and replace a character by another.
Point is: I never managed to do both since I know nothing about Regex.

I tried to manually join the Regex but it never worked:
`#ifndef ${TM_FILENAME/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/[\\.-]/_/g}`

expected result:
`#ifndef FILE_CLASS_HPP`
actual result:
`#ifndef ${TM_FILENAME/(.*)//upcase/[\.-]/_/g}`

Comment: Visual Studio [does not appear to support uppercasing via regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743836/is-it-possible-to-replace-to-uppercase-in-visual-studio).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The post you linked dates from 2012. You can see in the examples of the [VSC Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_transform-examples) that uppercasing using Regex is possible.

Comment: This is tough to do purely with regex.  Do the `#ifndef` names have a fixed number of dots in them, or could there be an arbitrary number of dots?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Unfortunately, the number of dots is arbitrary. It seems that there is a Regex to replace all occurrences of a character by another thought: `[\\.-]/_/g`. I just don't know how to combine it with the all uppercase Regex.

Comment: Yes, but the thing is, the regex you have in mind only works if you already have the string isolated and in hand, which is _not_ the case here.  For uppercasing, you have the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
"Filename upcase": {
  "prefix": "_uc",
  "body": [
    "#ifndef ${TM_FILENAME/([^\\.]*)(\\.)*/${1:/upcase}${2:+_}/g}"
  ],
  "description": "Filename uppercase and underscore"
},
```

---

```
([^\\.]*)(\\.)*  group1: all characters before a period
                 group2: the following period
```

replace with uppercase all the group1's: `${1:/upcase}`

replace all the group2s `'`'s with `_`'s

The `${2:+_}` is a **conditional replacement**, so you only add a `_` at the end of group1 uppercase **if** there is a following group2.

The `g` global flag is necessary in this case to catch all the occurrences of group1group2's, not just the first.