# How To do this in Regex - code base alterations

Tags: java, regex

I have a complete Java based code base, where members are named:

```
String m_sFoo;
Array m_arrKeepThings;
```

Variable/object names includes both a `m_` prefix to indicate a member, and an hungarian notation type indicator.

I'm looking for a way to perform a single time code replacment to (for example on the above to cases):

```
Array keepThings;
String foo;
```

Of course there are many other alternatives, but I hope that based on two examples, I'll be able to perform the full change.
Performances is not an issue as it's a single time fix.

To clarify, if I had to explain this in lines, it would be:

1. Match words starting with m_[a-zA-Z].
2. After m_, drop whatever is there before the first Capital letter.
3. **Change the first capital letter to lower case**.

Comment: Why you dont use the refactoring features of your IDE?

Comment: Because changing 8k variable names across 3k files, is a little too much for me.

Comment: I think a regex is not enough, you may need to understand the AST to perform those changes (depends on code complexity). Step #1 is maybe too generic, must can only match arribute names.

Comment: Thanks. Suely enough, I expect to have an additional 10% of the work done manually, it's the first chunk where I need help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some Java code that works. It is not pure regex, but based on:

**Usage:**

```
String str = "String m_sFoo;\n"
        + "Array m_arrKeepThings;\n"
        + "List<? extends Reader> m_lstReaders; // A silly comment\n"
        + "String.format(\"Hello World!\"); /* No m_named vars here */";
// Read the file you want to handle instead

NameMatcher nm = new NameMatcher(str);
System.out.println(nm.performReplacements());
```

**NameMatcher.java**

```
package so_6806699;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 *
 * @author martijn
 */
public class NameMatcher
{

    private String input;
    public static final String REGEX = "m_[a-z]+([A-Z0-9_\\$\\µ\\£]*)";
    public static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(REGEX);

    public NameMatcher(String input)
    {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public String performReplacements()
    {
        Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(input);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        int oldEnd = 0;
        while (m.find())
        {
            int start = m.start();
            int end = m.end();

            String match = input.substring(start, end);
            String matchGroup1 = match.replaceAll(REGEX, "$1");
            if (!matchGroup1.isEmpty())
            {
                char[] match_array = matchGroup1.toCharArray();
                match_array[0] = Character.toLowerCase(match_array[0]);
                match = new String(match_array);
            }

            sb.append(input.substring(oldEnd, start));
            oldEnd = end;

            sb.append(match);
        }
        sb.append(input.substring(oldEnd));
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**Demo Output**:

```
String foo;
Array keepThings;
List<? extends Reader> readers; // A silly comment
String.format("Hello World!"); /* No m_named vars here */
```

**Edit 0**:
Since dollar signs (`$`), micro (`µ`) and pound (`£`) are valid characters for Java name variables, I edited the regex.

**Edit 1:** It seems that there are a lot of non-latin characters that are valid (`éùàçè`, etc). Hopefully you don't have to handle them.

**Edit 2:** I'm only a human being! So be aware of errors there might be in the code! ***Make a BACKUP first!***

**Edit 3:** Code improved. A NPE was thrown when the code contains this: `m_foo`. These will be unhandled.

Comment: This is very close, but I'm having problem completing this in a real life scenario where I need to ename the member when being used as well, as in: **this.m_sFoo**; probbaly an additional match pattern ?

Comment: So, do you want to remove the `this.` part as well? I don't think that's a great idea. I think the code I gave you should work good.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really, really sure that the proposed changed won't result in clashes (variables that only differ in their prefix) I would do it with a line of perl:

```
perl -pi.bak -e "s/\bm_[a-z_]+([A-Z]\w*)\b/this.\u$1/g;" *.java
```

This will perform an inline edit of your Java sources, while keeping a backup with extension `.bak` replacing your pattern between word boundaries (`\b`) capitalising the first letter of the replacement (`\u`) multiple times per line.

You can then perform a diff between the backup files and the result files to see if all went well.

Comment: (1+) Hm, maybe it's time for me to learn a little perl, the "the Swiss Army chainsaw of programming languages"!

Comment: Wait!!! Pay attention. You probably should replace the m_A to `this.\u$1`. This will avoid name clashes with local variables.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this post: [Regex to change to sentence case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039226/regex-to-change-to-sentence-case)

Generally I am afraid that you cannot change the case of letters using regular expressions. 
I'd recommend you to implement a simple utility (using any language you want). You can do it in java. Just go through your file tree, search for pattern like `m_[sidc]([A-Z])`, take the captured sequence, call toLowerCase() and perform replace.

Other solution is to search and replace for `m_sA`, then `m_sB`, ... `m_sZ` using eclipse. Total: 26 times. It is a little bit stupid but probably anyway faster than implementing and debugging of your own code.