# Capitalizing the first letter after a tag

Tags: regex, capitalization

I'm trying to come up with a search and replace method for capitalizing the first letter after a tag, but I've had no luck.

I'm using the regex mode of `Notepad++`.

Comment: EDIT: I have already searched through the provided answers on the site and they were either (a) unhelpful or (b)irrelevant with regards to my question.

Comment: You could brute force it. Replace "<p>a" with "<p>A" and so on.

Comment: Did you see this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039226/regex-to-change-to-sentence-case

Comment: @shawnt00 I also tried using brute force as you put it but that didn't work either. And I saw that thread but the expression used by that person to match their text doesn't work for me.

Comment: You were probably having problems with the angle brackets because you still had regular expressions selected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Notepad++, enable regex mode in the Find and Replace dialog box, then find:

```
(?<=<p>)(.)
```

and replace with:

```
\U\1
```

To explain the pattern to be matched:

```
(?<=a)b   # A positive lookbehind, i.e. match all b that immediately follow a, but
          #   don't match the "a" itself.
(.)       # Find any character (i.e. "."), and capture it.
(?<=a)(.) # Find any character that immediately follows a, and capture it.
```

And the replacement:

```
\1   # The first captured substring in each match.
\Ux  # Convert x to upper case.
\U\1 # Convert the first captured substring in each match to upper case.
```

Note that this attempts to convert the first *character* to upper case. If there might be other non-letter characters between the `<p>` and the letter that you want capitalised, you could the pattern:

```
(?<=<p>)([^A-Za-z]*)(.) 

# [^x]       Matches any character that is not x.
# [^A-Za-z]  Matches any character that is not one of the upper case 
#              or lower case letters.
# x*         Matches zero or more consecutive x.
# [^A-Za-z]* Matches zero or more consecutive characters that are not
#              upper case or lower case letters.
```

and replace with

```
\1\U\2 # The first captured substring (any non-letter characters
       #   that immediately follow <p>) followed by the second captured
       #   substring (the first letter that appears after <p>), which 
       #   is converted to upper case.
```

The pattern to be found says: "match (and capture, in capture group 1) any non-letter characters that immediately follow `<p>`, and then match (and capture, in capture group 2) the first character that immediately follows the non-letter characters (which must, of course, be the letter we want to ensure is upper case)". Note that because we use `*`, a match will also result when there are no non-letter characters following `<p>`, in which case capture group one will just hold an empty string.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for both the solution and the explanation. I was honestly losing hair over this! Much appreciation!

Comment: @jbaum Am I missing something? Why do you need a lookback?

Comment: I see. It's not essential per se, it just makes the replacement easier.

Comment: @shawnt00 - you're right it's not essential, finding e.g. `<p>([^A-Za-z]*)(.) ` and replacing with `<p>\1\U\2` would also work. Good point.

Comment: Instead of changing the content of each tag value, im trying changing the first letter of the tag like <a to <A but just changing (?<=<p>)(.) to (?<=<)(.) ist not working. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
/<p>\s*(.){1}/
```

This will match a `<p>` tag followed by any kind of whitespace zero or more times, followed by any character 1 time and it will remember the 1 character so that you can use it later to turn it to uppercase.

Comment: Hmm so I tried to use this to match to my text but it's not working. It is isn't matching my text.

Comment: So here's my example text <p>my dog died yesterday</p> I was able to match using this ^<p>. However, it's the replacement that's giving me problems. Perhaps I'm just inputting your answer wrong?

Comment: Perhaps I'm doing this wrong but this isn't matching (finding) at all. I've input this answer in the "find what" section of the search/replace feature but it isn't able to find the "text".

Comment: @eams ok, apparently notepad++ does some things differently in regards to regular expressions compared to javascript. I am sorry, I had not considered that. Know that the general idea of my regex above is sound, and it should work, provided it is written in a way n++ understands. See here, it may help you http://letconex.blogspot.gr/2013/06/how-to-use-regular-expressions-in.html

Comment: @Mitch Thanks for the link. I think my real problem is not knowing how to properly string together the expressions.

Comment: @eams - sorry about your dog.