# VS Project References Broken On Case Sensitivity of GUID

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intellisense, roslyn-code-analysis

Since upgrading to VS 2015, my team has experienced random quirky things which I'm sure are being worked out at Microsoft right now.  One pretty annoying one is that we seem to lose project references, especially after branching.  I began to work on a new branch of our solution yesterday only to find out that types were unrecognized and namespace usings were being cited as unnecessary (because they were for the types that had suddenly become unrecognized).

The references in the project did not show any icons indicating a problem with the reference, but just to see if it would work, I removed and re-added a project reference, which caused its types to be recognized once more.

This, of course, updated the project file, so I looked to see what changes had been made.  The only difference between the project that could not detect the reference and the one that now can is that the alpha characters in the GUID had been changed from lower case to upper case.  For example:

Old, broken reference:

```
<ProjectReference Include="path/redacted">
    <Project>{95d34b2e-2ceb-499e-ab9e-b644b0af710d}</Project>
    <Name>Project.Name.Redacted</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

New, fixed reference:

```
<ProjectReference Include="path/redacted">
    <Project>{95D34B2E-2CEB-499E-AB9E-B644B0AF710D}</Project>
    <Name>Project.Name.Redacted</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

I'm looking for the reason this is happening and how I might fix it without having to manually remove and re-add references all over the place (and without having to convert all the project file GUIDs to upper case).

I should note that these "broken" references are not breaking the build, and that they only show up in the Error List as IntelliSense error, not build errors.  So, the references aren't really broken, they've just broken IntelliSense (which is arguably worse?!).

Comment: I've had this issue as well... A regex search with a bit of powershell does wonders... I've pinged the product team to see if there is a workaround.

Comment: @jessehouwing - Wowzers, how does one ping the product team?  You don't happen to have your regex and PS script still around, do you?

Comment: Having met a lot of them personally and being an MVP has its perks :). No I don't have the powershell handy... The format for Guid is quite uniform :) the method to uppercase is quite simple ;).

Comment: Pinging them again. Last response: "Thanks for the report – I wasn’t aware of this issue, but we’ll take a look."

Comment: I don't think this quite constitutes an answer, but I did fix my problem.  After completely removing the solution from my system and getting it from source control again, the problem persisted.  However, later, just to be sure, I did the same process once more and that fixed it.  Oh, the mysteries of Visual Studio.

Comment: This bug is still present in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

Comment: We also have this problem in VS 2015, update 3. And it causes failures in solution rebuild for our large solution (60+ projects). Batch builds using MSBuild are fine, it's only when rebuilding from Visual Studio that we have the problem Upper-casing the references solves.

Comment: Strange: I had to convert the alpha characters in the project reference in the csproj file to lower case to get the VS build working...

Comment: I ran into this problem, except that my coworker **could** build the exact same branch when I could not.  I deleted my `*.suo` file from the solution's `.vs` folder and this fixed the problem for me, allowing me to build the solution.  This probably explains why MSBuild is not affected, but as to why user settings of a solution causes the case-sensitivity problem...

Comment: VS 2017, the bug is still alive and kicking. Maybe in VS 2019 this will be resolved :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Visual Studio isn't entirely consistent about how it assigns GUIDs to projects *or* how it specifies those GUIDs in project references. I was able to resolve the problem by using upper case GUIDs with braces for `ProjectGuid` elements and lower case with braces for `Project` elements (in references).

**Background**

We have a large solution (60+ C# projects), and were having regular issues with solution Rebuild as incorrect build order would cause failure to resolve referenced projects that had not yet been built (but should have been). Build Dependencies and Build Order appeared correct. MSBuild batch build worked fine, it was only a problem when rebuilding from Visual Studio.

Forcing all project GUIDs to upper case with braces and all project reference GUIDs to lower case with braces fixed the problem. This is *usually* how Visual Studio generates these GUIDs, but not always.

Doing some investigation in a brand new test solution, it turns out that:

1. Generated GUIDs for console application projects are upper case with braces.
2. Generated GUIDs for class library projects are initially lower case with no braces.
3. If a new project reference is added a class library project with a lower case GUID, then not only is the reference GUID added, but the project GUID is converted to upper case with braces.
4. If a copy of a class library project is made and then added to the solution then its GUID is replaced with a new one that uses upper case and braces. (But if a copy is made and its GUID manually removed, Visual Studio does not insert a replacement GUID into the .csproj file.)
5. Project references GUIDs are usually use lower case and braces, but somehow our project had accumulated a bunch of upper case GUID references.
6. GUIDs in the .sln always use upper case and braces.

I was able to fix our broken rebuild by replacing the reference GUIDs with either all upper case or all lower case -- it's something about the mix of upper and lower case that was giving Visual Studio problems (perhaps case-sensitive string keys in a dictionary somewhere?) Since Visual Studio normally adds references with lower case GUIDs, that is the option I chose to go with.

**Regex Search & Replace**

To fix this, I used Notepad++ regex-based search and replace in files to force all ProjectGuids in .csproj files to be upper case with braces (the default for console applications, and the style Visual Studio will apply after adding any project reference to the project):

```
Find what: (<ProjectGuid>)\{?([0-9a-f-]+)\}?(</ProjectGuid>)
Replace with: \1{\U\2}\E\3
Search in: *.csproj
```

Be sure to turn on regular expression search, and turn off match case. And don't search all files, or you may make changes you don't want, for example in *.xproj files, as noted by @AspNyc. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16830360/503688) for additional info on use of regular expressions for changing case.)

I then replaced all references to projects to use lower case with braces (which is what Visual Studio usually does):

```
Find what: (<Project>)\{?([0-9a-f-]+)\}?(</Project>)
Replace with: \1{\L\2}\E\3
Search in: *.csproj
```

Having made these changes, Visual Studio solution rebuild now works reliably. (At least until next time rogue upper case reference GUIDs sneak into our project.)

Comment: I will look more at the details soon, but wanted to comment on the TL;DR-- I have no reason to believe anyone copy-and-pasted a CSPROJ as a template when our team experienced these issues.

Comment: Hmm, I'm also continuing to work with my fix. I just noticed that when a reference is added to a C# project, the ProjectGuid will switch from lowercase no braces to uppercase with braces. So lower-casing everything may not be the ongoing solution after all. I will continue to experiment then come back and revise my answer accordingly.

Comment: I know I will be using this the (inevitable) next time our GUIDs go nuts.  Good job and getting this all worked out!

Comment: @bubbleking I think this sorted the build issues we were having, too -- great job!  One thing to note: you might want to constrain your find/replace search to `*.csproj` files.  Reason being, `*.xproj` files -- .NET Core project files -- appear to use GUIDS with no leading or curly braces.  So when I tried your posted solution, it also added braces where there hadn't been any before.

Comment: @AspNyc, yep, I only converted *.csproj files. I did say "in .csproj files" but I could have been more clear about the Find & Replace options, sorry.

Comment: @yoyo Nothing to apologize for -- your post helped solve some really frustrating build issues I'd been seeing!  I just wanted to share what I stumbled over initially, to clarify things a bit.

Answer (score 9):

I suffered a similar issue when updating VS2017 v15.7 to v15.9.

The answer for me was to close down VS, clear out the hidden `.vs` folder in my solution's root directory and restart VS.

Comment: Just had this show up in VS2017 v15.8 as well. In our case, removing and re-referencing the project added the Guid back in lowercase.

Your fix did the job, and we are updating to v15.9 currently.

Comment: Thanks, it helps for VS 2017 Professional 15.9.13 as well

Answer (score 6):

There's a bug in the projectsystem it seems. This powershell will loop over projects and make all references upper case:

```
#FixGuids

get-childitem -recurse | ?{ @('.sln', '.csproj', '.vbproj') -contains $_.Extension } | %{
   [regex]::Replace((gc -raw $_.FullName), '[{(]?[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}[-]?([0-9A-Fa-f]{4}[-]?){3}[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}[)}]?', { return ([string]$args[0]).ToUpperInvariant() }) |
      Out-File $_.FullName -Encoding "UTF8
}
```

It's quite simplistic. If you rely on guids in your projects for something other than references, you may want to turn it into something more intelligent.

Comment: Since I had already fixed my problem, I tested this by making some dummy text files with the extensions .csproj, .vbproj and .sln.  Then I saved some lorem ipsum along with several GUIDs into each file and ran this script on the directory.  The result was that the contents of the files were completely erased.  Is there something about my way of testing this that would have caused this?

Comment: It may have been me including the write-host of the file name. PS does strange things when methods write to the output...

Comment: Here's hoping they knocked this bug out in VS15 Update 2!

Comment: Here's hoping they knock this bug out in VS15 Update 4!

Comment: Make that Visual Studio 2017. I won't be expecting an update 4 for 2015.

Comment: That script made my project files unreadable ... and all on one line

Comment: You can specify the -Raw flag for `gc` to return a string instead of an array of strings, and then there shouldn't be one-line files.

Comment: I had to add the encoding `Out-File $_.FullName -Encoding "UTF8"`. Otherwise I got the error: _'.' hexadecimal value 0x00 is an invalid character. line 2 position 1_

Answer (score 3):

In order to use the answer in a git hook, I had to convert it to sed's regex syntax:

```
sed -r "s/(<Project>\{?)([0-9A-F-]+)(\}?<\/Project>)/\1\L\2\E\3/g" sample.csproj
```

Maybe someone finds this useful.

Answer (score 1):

Today in visual studio 2019 (16.2.2) I was encountering build system issues where projects were being unnecessarily (and repeatedly) rebuilt whenever I initiated the building of my solution.

(None of the usual steps resolved the build issues, eg deleting the ".vs" folder, or deleting "bin" and "obj" directories, etc).

At first it appeared to be related to the character-casing of guids, because I was able to get the problem to go away by editing the guids and saving the project.  However that was a red-herring ... I was unwittingly fixing the problem by changing the timestamps of all my csproj files.  The build system seemed a lot happier after those timestamps were updated, and it stopped the annoying behavior (continuously attempting to rebuild projects that had already been built.)

The character casing of the guids didn't end up being the problem at all.  As far as I can tell, VS 2019 is ok with both upper- and lower-case guids.   They can even mismatch the source project, based on my experimentation (eg. the original source project can use uppercase and referencing projects can use lowercase).

If it is helpful to anyone, below is a powershell that will let you adjust the write-time of all csproj files under a path.  This will be another trick I use whenever the msbuild system is misbehaving in visual studio.

```
$datenow = get-date

$files = Get-ChildItem -path "C:\Data\Workspaces\LumberTrack\" -recurse | where { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} 

foreach ($file in $files)
{
if ($file.Extension -eq ".csproj") 
{
   Set-ItemProperty $file.FullName LastWriteTime $datenow
   Write-Output $file.FullName
}    
}    
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for sharing that; the script is especially helpful. If you have access to ReSharper, I also recommend trying their build tool. It supposedly does a better analysis of what projects actually need rebuilding, thus saving time. Maybe its results would have been better in this case too.